# How to change row names of a particular column in the same way in R

Tags: r

I am new in R and I have a very basic question.

MY ID column in my data frame is like this:

```
ID 
100-01
101-01
500-01
499-01 
.
.
```

And I want to convert those "-01" to "-02". How can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use `base::sub`: `df$ID = sub("[-]01$", "-02", df$ID)`.

Comment: Perhaps using sub, e.g. `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(ID = sub("-01", "-02", ID))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub`

```
  df$ID <- sub("-01", "-02", df$ID)
  df
      ID
1 100-02
2 101-02
3 500-02
4 499-02
```